# why all Arabic regional formats uses US numerals

Tags: language-support, input-language, arabic, system-language

As language source is set to Arabic system should output ٠ ١ ٢ ٣ instead of 0 1 2 3, noting that my regional formats are set to Arabic (jordan)

Comment: Please provide more details. Where do you want you to have arabic numbers? In terminal or in word processor?

Comment: I would like to have it System wide

Comment: `0123` are Arabic digits used in North Africa, `٠١٢٣` are Arabic-Indic digits used in Middle East. See Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

- **In LibreOffice:** Go to:

> Tools > Options > Language settings > Complex  text layout

Then choose *context* or *Hindi* instead of *Arabic*.

- **In terminal:**

Download [this](https://launchpad.net/~behnam/+archive/ppa/+build/574789/+files/bicon_0.2.0-1ubuntu0~ppa4_amd64.deb) package, it's a .deb file; you can install it using:

```
sudo apt install ./name.deb (or sudo apt install /path/to/package/name.deb)
```

For further information, look at this links:

[Link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77657/how-to-enable-arabic-support-in-gnome-terminal)

[Link2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123756/how-to-make-arabic-appear-properly-in-linux-terminal)

[Link3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661661/arabic-numbers-dates-showing-in-various-places)

[Arabic community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Arabic)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Ubuntu 20

1. Go to `setting`
2. Choose `region & language`
3. In `input sources` click the `+`
4. Choose from `Arabic(Jordan)` `Arabic(qwerty/digits)`
5. Remove the old Arabic language from garbage icon that in its raw

That's all. Problem should be fixed system wide now.
This idea I take it from
[this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1064654/973406)

[image: this is the final setting screenshot]